# How to scale a data series on a Kusto timechart

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I want to scale a data series on a time chart so that it is visible with the other series.  The first two series represent successfully and failed `requests` with the 3rd series representing a `customEvent` of the application attempting to correct itself.  All three series get plotted but the restart series is essentially a line at 0 due to the relative difference in magnitudes.  The documentation for the `ysplit` option of the  [`render`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/renderoperator) operator suggests that `axes` would provide what I am looking for but none of the values seem to affect the graph.

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(3d) and name has "POST /v1/validation"
| union customEvents |  where timestamp > ago(3d)
| extend Event=case(itemType == 'request' and success == "True", "Succeeded", itemType == "request" and success == "False", "Failed", "Restarted")
| summarize Count=count() by Event, bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Here is the time chart that gets rendered with the Restarted series but the highest number within a bucket is 2 so it is essentially a flat line at the origin.

[image: Kusto Timechart]

**Update 5/3**

The UX client is the Application Insights Analytics widget of the Azure portal.

Comment: 'render' operator acts as hint for client tool, and each tool may have different rendering capabilities/features supported. Can you please share what UX is referred in this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use ysplit to create a custom y-axis for each series:

```
range timestamp from ago(3d) to now() step 1m
| extend Event = rand(100)
| extend EventCategory = case(
            Event < 80, 1, 
            Event < 99, 2,
            3)
| summarize Count=count() by tostring(EventCategory), bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render timechart with (ysplit=axes)
```

I can't run your query to be sure, but I would think that maybe just adding `with (ysplit=axes)` to the end would be enough to give you the desired behavior.